# How to add line behind/under text with html/css in the divi WordPress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, divi-theme

So im trying to add a line behind/under my text which i have partially manged to do (see attached.) [image]

To get the above outcome i added the following code into the :after section of the Divi theme's text module custom css option:

```
content: '';
position: absolute;
bottom: 15px !important;
left: 6px;
right: -10px;
height: 13px;
background: #25c6fe;
width: 19.8%;
```

I have ***two*** problems:

- When saving the page it puts the line underneath the text.
- If i center the text the line stays to the left

How can i fix these probelms? I assume the css is wrong?

Comment: There's a billion reason's this could happen.  Can you post a link to your site if its online? if not can you post your html code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might result in a unnecessary complex css code, if you try to use `:after` to make your desired styling. Starting with the `width` property, which should always have the length of the element, because you want the whole text to be underlined, no matter how long it is. So I would suggest you try using the `background-image` property to make things work:

```
.your_textmodule_class {
    color: black;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 85%, #25c6fe 0);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

With the transparent percentage value, you can set the height of the line. Use less percent, if you want the line to have more height. Looking at your image, I think something like `linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 70%, #25c6fe 0)` could be what you want to achieve.

Comment: With slightly to one side, do you mean that the line starts a bit earlier than the text? You can do this with setting ´padding´ to the side you like (i.e. padding-left: 20px;), and take the same value als negative ´margin´ (margin-left: -20px;) to have the same position of the text as before.

Comment: Perfect thanks. I have to use negative margin on the left and positive padding on the right to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok get rid of that whole class and styles and everything about it that you made for that underline bar and do it this way by only adding to your `.et_pb_text_1` CSS. Add this `border-bottom: 10px solid #25c6fe` and display it as a table-cell.

so like this:

```
.et_pb_text_1 {
  border-bottom: 10px solid #25c6fe;
  display: table-cell
}
```

Comment: Thats great thanks. I'm just trying to figure out that huge white gap

Comment: ignore the `after` part, I updated my code. also added display: table-cell but you should use `border-bottom: 10px solid #25c6fe;` to do this effect, don' make a seperate item to do it,

Comment: Any idea how to align these?  If so let me know and i'll publish another question

Comment: What are you trying to align?

Comment: Ok I looked at your site, do this: `.et_pb_section_1.et_pb_section {  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;}` and it should do what you want.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for that but thats not what i was trying. I've posted the full question here so you can get some points :) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61822971/how-to-left-center-right-align-a-table-cell

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try:

```css
.mytext{
color: black;
    background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 70%, #25c6fe 0);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="mytext">Host an event</h1>
```

Hope it works. :)