# How to left/center/right align a table cell

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On this page https://stephenb14.sg-host.com/heading/ i have 3 headings that are created using.

```
display: table-cell;
```

I had to create them that way to display the borderline in the way i wanted. Now I am trying to align each heading to the left, right and center. I used:

```
text-align: right;
```

But it doesn't do anything.

How can i left/right/center the table cells?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.et_pb_section_1.et_pb_section { display: flex; justify-content: center;}
```

it should work as I've tested it on your site:

[image]

Comment: Hi John, sorry i didnt explain properly on the last thread. Im actually trying to align only the text on the row. Left align should be to the left, center should be center and right to the right on their individual rows. I just put 3 rows up and set them to the alignment i wanted to see if i could figure out why it wasn't working

Comment: I still don't understand, could you possibly make a simple diagram even using mspaint of what you want?

Comment: Thanks for your patience with me haha. Please check the page again, i've shown at the bottom what im trying to do

Comment: If that's the case I would look into making a grid.  See here for how to do it: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_grid_layout_named